# exception handling to display a MessageBox when compute button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, try-catch

[This is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Asn.png)

I designed this Windows Form Application. If the compute button is clicked and there is no text in the text box i used a try catch block to show a message box of the error. But when i click the button without entering a text in the text box, nothing happens. Here's my code;

```
    Dim textBox As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'throws an exception if text box input is empty
    Try
        textBox = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("enter text in text box")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Try

    'if there's no error execute some code below

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Try...Catch,` block? Use a simple `If...Else` statement to check `If TextBox1.Text.Trim = String.Empty`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle this is using the `Validating` event of the `TextBox`. You handle the event and, in it, you validate the data and set `e.Cancel` to `True` if it fails. That will prevent the field losing focus until valid data is entered. You can then call `ValidateChildren` in your `Button.Click` event handler to force all controls to be validated, even if they haven't received focus. It will return a `Boolean` that indicates whether all children passed validation or not.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim() = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter some text")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        'All data is valid so proceed to use it.

        Dim str = TextBox1.Text
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```